# What to do about the broken Android Upgrade

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

Today I upgraded the Android SDK tool-chain. Because I was asked to do so. After the frist upgrade I got the following error message when compiling my project:

```
[INFO] Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\opt\android-sdk-windows\tools\proguard\lib\proguard.jar
```

And indeed `proguard.jar` went missing. However I also noticed that after the first upgrade round `SDK Manager.exe` wanted to install even more packages. After doing so the missing jar file repapered. But now the build ends with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:zipalign (alignApk) on project  …: MojoExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Coul
d not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C "C:\opt\android-sdk-windows\tools\zipalign.exe … Result = 1 -> [Help 1]
```

And indeed `zipalign.exe` went missing. What is to be done? Another installation round or is the SDK broken beyond repair?

**UPDATE 1:**

A complete reinstall did not do the trick `zipalign.exe` is still missing.

**UPDATE 2:**

`zipalign` is missing on Mac OS X as well.

Comment: Download and reinstall Android IDE takes 10 minutes - much less than fixing Eclipse hardly working update system.

Comment: @Marius Not with our super fast company internet connection. But yes: I do precisely that right now.

Comment: One I accidentally removed my Executable file from Eclipse, and replaced it with a copy from newly downloaded adt bundle and it worked. With luck, simply adding missing filed by hand might work for you.

Comment: @Marius — a complete reinstall did not help either. But getting the exe from coogle code did. What a waste of time. And BTW: I don't use Eclipse. I use Maven and IntelliJ IDEA — and so for years now.

Answer (score 0):

Since even a complete reinstall did not do the trick I got a `zipalign.exe` from https://code.google.com/p/apkclean/downloads/list .